# Amazon EC2 - Windows Server 2008 R2 DC - SharePoint 2010 Foundation

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, licensing, amazon-ec2

We have an application running in the Amazon EC2 environment on a Windows Server 2008 R2 (Data Center edition) VM with SQL licensing (added as part of the hourly figure).

Now we have an application that runs SharePoint 2010 Foundation that is for employees of our organisation, around 30,000 of them. These users authenticate with the application through forms auth. Every user has to be authenticated and is officially a 'member of staff' at the company.

In terms of Microsoft licensing, this is where we are confused. It is our understanding that:

- The Windows Server 2008 R2 DC license is provided by Amazon EC2 as part of the hourly fee paid
- SQL Server 2008 is licensed under the same agreement through EC2
- The SharePoint Foundation 2010 license is provided under the Windows Server 2008 license

Now after this we don't know what further licenses we require. There has been talk of External Connector licenses, or individual CAL's for each user (30,000 of them!).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no separate Licensing for the SharePoint Foundation as this is covered under the Windows OS license.

I would recommend to contact Amazon EC2 team and ask them about what kind of license you have VL and how many user covered under this?

> Every user or device that accesses or uses the Windows Server 2008 or
>   Windows Server 2008 R2 server software requires the purchase of a
>   Windows Server 2008 Client Access License (Windows Server CAL) except
>   under the following circumstances:
>
> If access to the instances of server software is only through the
>   Internet without being authenticated or otherwise individually
>   identified by the server software or through any other means
>
> If external users are accessing the instances of server software and
>   you have acquired a Windows Server 2008 External Connector license for
>   each server being accessed